# calling function inside js file from script inside rails view file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view

I am beginner to ruby on rails what I want to do in my application is call java script function from script define inside view file like in following manner

```
//code inside js file ...
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("outside the function");
function abc()
{
    alert("inside function");
}
});

//code in side view file 
<div> creating view here </div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    abc();
</script>
```

But It not giving require output. It shows one alert i.e. outside the function. But not showing other one that mean not calling that function. I want to call that function ...
How to do this? Any solution? 
Need help ... Thank you ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you need to move your function `abc()` outside the jQuery `ready` wrapper function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("outside the function");

});

function abc(){
    alert("inside function");
}
```